# How to acess Private function of another class in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a **dbHandeller.php**  file . as follow

```
class dbHandeler {

    var $conn;

 public function __construct(){

        $this->initiatedb();

 }

    private function initiatedb(){

        //Details of the Databse
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "xxxxxx";

            // Create connection
            $this->conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if (!$this->conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }else
               return $this->conn;

    }

 private function sql_query($query){

 }

}
```

Then I have **donation.php** and it extends the DB class

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

class donation extends dbHandeler{


    public function __construct(){

        $dbObj = new dbHandeler();
        $dbObj->initiatedb();
    }

    public function putDonation(){
        var_dump($_POST);

    }

    public function getDonation(){


    }
}
```

When I try to access the `donation` class I am getting following error

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Call to private method dbHandeler::initiatedb() from context 'donation' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\templeform\api\donation.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

error
```

Comment: They are `private` right ?

Comment: @RayonDabre yes , So if I am extending the class then I should be able to access the private class right ?

Comment: use `Reflection` to do the same.

Comment: @prava can you post an answer for the same

Comment: private functions cant be accessed outside the class

Comment: No: private is for the class itself. protected allows access for extended classes, and (of course) public allows for any.

Comment: change the method to `protected`, so extending classes will be able to access it

Comment: @shubham so should I initialize them as protected ??

Comment: @drndavi yes got it thanks

Comment: yes you can access the protected function in child class

Comment: you can not access a private function outside its parent class, you must learn difference between Public, Private and Protected Functions.

Answer (score 6):

The **"private"** access specifier is meant to be available within the class it is defined only, you cannot call it from outside the class it is defined in, even from a child class. You can maybe use the **"protected"** access specifier instead which will be available to the child classes as well but not the other classes. Hope this helps.

Comment: better if you add this info as comment, it can not be treated as an Answer

Comment: @Insomania He can't post comments with 1 reputation

Comment: Thanks for talking some sense in to him @dave

Answer (score 0):

If the method is private, there is a reason, why the method is private. A private functions could only be called inside the class. If the method should be available in inherited classes, you should mark the function protected.
If the function should be accessible from everywhere, it must be public.

If you want to change the accessibility of the function, you could do so with `ReflectionMethod::setAccessible` - but doing this is most often a good indicator for a bad design.

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('dbHandeler', 'sql_query');
$method->setAccessible(true);
```

If you dont want to change the accessibility, you could also use reflection to invoke the method directly, which might be the better option.

Nevertheless you should really think about you design. If this is your own class, why don't you just mark the function public or protected?